# How long it takes until all dragons resurrect?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

According with the game, Alduin is reviving dragons buried in the dragon mounds. So, how long it takes until all of them are alive?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alduin reviving dragons is just an in-universe explanation of where the dragons are coming from. No matter how long you play, there will always be more dragons to fight, even if you beat Alduin at the end of the base game. They simply keep spawning.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this answers the question. The question seemed to be wanting to know how long it takes for the dragons to respawn, not how they are respawning.

Comment: @Ramirez They are asking how long it takes for *all* dragons to revive. There is no "all dragons", because there's an infinite number of them.

Comment: The OP just may be under the misconception that since there is a finite number of burial mounds, there is a finite number of dragons that spawn

Comment: @Wondercricket that's what I was thinking as well once I read this.

Comment: I'm not even sure the actual burial mounds change in game.  As I'm wandering around, I know you can see some that are empty, and some that are still full, but I've never noticed if a given mound will appear full at one point in the game and then appear empty later (with exception of the ones that actually play the resurrecting mini-scene with the named dragons, like Karthwasten, where the mound obviously changes after the mini-scene).

Comment: Actually I want to know if all dragons in burial mounds are resurrected by Alduin.

Comment: @Ethan No.  You only ever witness one resurrection.  The rest are assumed to be resurrected.  In terms of actual game-play mechanics, they either respawn via time or via a radiant quest.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking about dragons in general? – then Mge Xy’s answer should do. But in case you are asking about their buried types (named ones), that Alduin is reviving with a shout, I think that if you follow the order on the map that is given to you by Farengar Secret-Fire you will get all the buried dragons revived. The first one was near Windhelm, between miners settlement and orsimer’s stronghold. That's all I remember unfortunately for I’ve lost this map the next day after I received it (put it on a display in my Hearthfire DLC house and it fall through the textures while loading the next time I came).

In case You meant the exact amount of time between dragon attacks - my 105 lvl character (adept lvl difficulty) was always (through all the 105 lvls and 10k+ hrs of gameplay) attacked after 3-5 fast travels/visited locations as I was passing by random NPC spawn areas (dragons, bandits, paddlers, daedra, vampires and etc.). So I literally knew beforehand that this time it is ok not to save game and that time – I’d better save it in case dragon won’t pick up the fight (those cowards x_X).

Answer (score 2):

As noted, there are an infinite number of generic dragons. Once you flip the trigger to start their spawning, they'll never stop unless you use a cheat/mod/et cetera to do so. So in that respect, they will never "all" be resurrected.

That said, there are a fixed number of [*named* dragons](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon#Named_Dragons) in the base game. [Four of these are known be alive](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Atlas_of_Dragons) at the start of the story (one of whom does not appear in Skyrim). Five more have known burial sites and are brought back by Alduin during the course of the main quest. They are:

- [Sahloknir](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sahloknir) at Kynesgrove, during A Blade in the Dark.
- [Nahagliiv](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nahagliiv) at Rorikstead, during A Cornered Rat.
- [Odahviing](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Odahviing) near Riften, during The Fallen.
- [Viinturuth](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Viinturuth), near Lake Yorgrim, after The Throat of the World.
- [Vuljotnaak](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vuljotnaak), near Sunderstone Gorge, during Diplomatic Immunity.

Of these, Odahviing is the last you'll encounter during the course of the main quest. Thus, it takes until the event of The Fallen before all the dragons Alduin will wake up are, in fact, awake.

The remaining base-game dragon, [Vulthuryol](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vulthuryol) can be found in Blackreach and presumably has been alive since before the events of story.